# What PCI self assessment questionnaire to choose?

Tags: pci-dss

We need to fill out a PCI self assessment questionnaire, and I am wondering If we need to fill out SAQ A-EP or SAQ D.

We are an e-commerce merchant that doesnt operate trough a website, but we  receive credit card details on our API. We tokenize it and send it to third-party PCI compliant service provider. We don't store any credit card details.

Comment: The first sentence under "_Before You Begin_" of the [SAQ A-EP document](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_A-EP_v3.pdf) includes "_ applicable to e-commerce merchants with a
website(s) that **does not itself receive cardholder data**_" so clearly does not apply. The corresponding sentence in [SAQ D](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_D_v3_Merchant.pdf) is "_SAQ D for Merchants applies to SAQ-eligible merchants not meeting the criteria for any other SAQ type_".

Comment: @TripeHound Please read my question carefully. I never mentioned a website, only an api service. Could you please provide me with a further explanation of a term website? Is an API service a website? Does an API fall under website category when we speak in PCI DSS language?

Comment: Assuming an "_e-commerce merchant_" has a (designed for human interaction) website is not, I think, unreasonable... if that's not the case, I suggest you [edit] the question to make it explicit. I strongly suspect that an internet-hosted API would count as "a website" as far as PCI DSS is concerned but am not certain. What probably matters more is "_does not itself receive cardholder data_". That your servers get such data is, I believe, sufficient to exclude you from SAQ A-EP.

Comment: Indeed, the second paragraph "_SAQ A-EP merchants are e-commerce merchants who partially outsource their e-commerce payment channel to PCI DSS validated third parties and do not electronically store, process, or transmit any cardholder data on their systems or premises_" makes no mention of "website". You are an "e-commerce merchant" who processes cardholder data, therefore cannot be "SAQ A-EP merchant".

Comment: I agree with you. If you want to move it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Can you first [edit] the question to clarify that you are not running a "conventional" website yourselves, but only operate an API (I'm guessing as some kind of third-party service on behalf of companies that _do_ have a human-facing website). In its current form, the question _appears_ to lack the level of basic research expected on StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The introduction to the [SAQ A-EP Document](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_A-EP_v3.pdf) (PDF) reads (emphasis mine):

> **Before You Begin**
>
> SAQ A-EP has been developed to address requirements applicable to e-commerce merchants with a website(s) **that does not itself receive cardholder data** but which does affect the security of the payment transaction and/or the integrity of the page that accepts the consumer’s cardholder data.
>
> SAQ A-EP merchants are e-commerce merchants who partially outsource their e-commerce payment channel to PCI DSS validated third parties and **do not electronically store, process, or transmit any cardholder data** on their systems or premises.

Your servers *receive cardholder data* (albeit via an API rather than through an interactive web-page) and *processes cardholder data* (to tokenize it before forwarding to a third-party site). Therefore my reading of the above is that **SAQ A-EP is not applicable**.

The use of the word *website* in the first paragraph is, presumably, to cover "normal" websites that hand both the *acquisition and processing* of cardholder data to another party: for instance by opening a new window or embedding an `<iframe>` in their webpage (and where the contents of the window/iframe is provided by the third-party and not your servers).

While one could debate whether "*website*" in the first paragraph includes a non-interactive API, I think that is irrelevant<sup>**1**</sup>. The second paragraph does *not* use "*website*" – it talks only of "*systems*" and "*channels*" – so would unambiguously apply to your situation. Since you *do* process cardholder data, you cannot be an "*SAQ A-EP merchant*".

Therefore, of the two, the SAQ D questionnaire would apply to your situation<sup>**2**</sup>.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> My strong suspicion is what *really* matters in the first paragraph (and this view is backed-up in the second paragraph) is the passage I highlighted, namely "*that does not itself receive cardholder data*". Even if your API *is not considered a website*, it *does* (or will) receive cardholder data, and therefore you would not be eligible for the (presumably less onerous) obligations of SAQ A-EP.

<sup>**2**</sup> Note that the introduction of [SAQ D](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_D_v3_Merchant.pdf) (PDF) reads "*SAQ D for Merchants applies to SAQ-eligible merchants **not meeting the criteria for any other SAQ type**.*". Of the two SAQs you mention, you clearly (in my mind) don't meet the criteria for *SAQ A-EP*. However, according to [Understanding the SAQs for PCI DSS version 3](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Understanding_SAQs_PCI_DSS_v3.pdf) (PDF), there are a number of other types. It's conceivable (though from a quick scan of the opening page, unlikely) that you could be eligible for one of those.